# Is there a good way to 'flip' a list/matrix of numbers around some non-zero value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to 'flip' the values in a matrix, similar to `numpy.absolute()`, but flipping around the average value in the matrix; sort of like a fold.

The code below works, but I'd ideally like something that's more pythonic / faster. For my purposes, my array is 360x360, and this 'flipping' needs to be done many, many times, so running a 'for' loop through each and every element in the array seems like a bad idea.

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
avg = np.average(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    x = arr[i]
    if x < avg:
        arr[i] = x + avg
print(arr)
>>> [2,3,2,3,4]
```

Thanks!

Comment: avg = np.average(data); data[data<avg]= data[data<avg] + avg

Answer (score 2):

This is the numpy way:

```
arr[arr < avg] += avg
```

The expression `arr < avg` creates a mask for selecting the elements in `arr` which are less than `avg`.

`arr[...]` selects those elements in `arr`.

`+= avg` increments them.